# How to check a detached daemon without a wallet?

Tags: daemon, full-node, linux, wallet

I have set a Monero node as a service on a virtual machine with `--detach` option to run it in the background. I can check the service status through Linux command or connect to the node with a wallet.

But, how can I check the detached daemon status without a wallet? Could I reattach the daemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just run commands like `monerod status` which connects to the detached process and runs the command (`status` in this example).

You can also use the daemons RPC [get_info](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info).

> But, how can I check the detached daemon status without a wallet?

A node does not have a wallet attached to it.

Comment: So, I need physical access to the server or ssh to it and to run another instance of the daemon to check the detached one. Right?

Comment: Nope. I think you missed reading the part in the answer that mentions calling the RPC's /get_info.

Comment: Ops, sorry for the explanation request. "You can also use the daemons RPC get_info." --> I understood it was an alternative because of "ALSO". Anyway, you gave me a good starting point, so I'm going to make some tests. Thanks!